# I have a large matrix with labeled columns, I need to find a way to end a grep

Tags: r, regex

My column names are

```
log_mat: AA(1)-Ib, AA(1)-Ib1, AA(1)-Ib2, AA(1)-Ib3, AA(1)-Ib4, AA(1)-Ib5
```

I've tried

```
grep("AA(1)-Ib", colnames(log_mat), fixed = TRUE)
```

It returns column index for all of the values, how would I get only `AA-Ib` returned

Comment: `grep("AA\\(1\\)-Ib$", colnames(log_mat))`

Comment: thank you so much, double escape was getting me :)

Answer (score 0):

The `grep()` function returns only index values, and the `grepl()` only returns logical values (TRUE, FALSE). In order to get these real values you are suppose to do the following:

```
selected.colnames <- colnames(log_mat)[grep("AA(1)-Ib", 
                                       colnames(log_mat), fixed = TRUE)]
```

Or:

```
selected.colnames <- colnames(log_mat)[grepl("AA(1)-Ib", 
                                       colnames(log_mat), fixed = TRUE)]
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep("AA\\(1\\)-Ib$", colnames(log_mat))`